# Rails console - output queries results table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, console

On rails console (just for the record, rails 3.2), how can I make it output to STDOUT my queries results table (ie: the table containing the columns names and values)?

```
User Load (6.5ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`
---------------------------
Id | Name | Address | Phone
---------------------------
1  | Sam  | ZZZ 10  | 55555
---------------------------
2  | xxxx | xxxxxxx | xxxxx
```

Tks!

ps: Note that query.explain is NOT what i need.

Comment: Are you looking for [hirb](https://github.com/cldwalker/hirb#readme)?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a gem to do exactly this! http://tableprintgem.com

[image: table_print ruby gem - explore your data]

The most powerful feature of table_print is the ability to see your data in the context of other objects it relates to. You can reference nested objects with the method chain required to reach them. This example is showing data from three different tables:

- **name** from the Author table (reached through author.name)
- **title** from the Book table (reached through author.books.title)
- **caption** from the Photo table (reached through author.books.photos.caption)

[image: table_print ruby gem - contextualize your data]

There's a short intro screencast at http://tableprintgem.com